# How can i carry the implementation of a member of a class template with arguments by default out of boundary this class template?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I work in VS 2010. I'm trying to expand functionality and redefine any functions of the multimap container:

```
// test_multimap.h

#include <map>

namespace std
{
     template <typename TKey, typename TData, 
            class Compare = less<TKey>,
            class Alloc = allocator<pair<const TKey, TData>>
            >
     class test_multimap: public multimap<TKey, TData, Compare, Alloc>
     {
     public:

         void clear()
         {
             multimap<TKey, TData>::clear();
         }

         /*...*/
```

This works, but if I try to carry out the implementation of member functions, I encounter some problems:

```
// test_multimap.h

#include <map>

namespace std
{

    template <typename TKey, typename TData, 
              class Compare = less<TKey>,
              class Alloc = allocator<pair<const TKey, TData>>
         >
    class test_multimap: public multimap<TKey, TData, Compare, Alloc>
    {
    public:

        void clear();
        /*...*/



// test_multimap.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "test_multimap.h"

namespace std
{

    template <typename TKey, typename TData,
              class Compare = less<TKey>,
              class Alloc = allocator<pair<const TKey, TData>>
             >
    void test_multimap<TKey, TData, Compare, Alloc>::clear()
    {
        multimap<TKey, TData>::clear();
    }

 }
```

In this case I get the error

> C4519 (template arguments by default can be used only in a class template)
>   In other cases i get the set of different errors.

How can I carry out the implementation of the template member functions??

Comment: You shouldn't publicly inherit from multimap, as it is an STL container, and doesn't have a virtual destructor. In certain cases, it can lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what the error suggests: don't use the defaults when defining the function and you will be fine.

```
namespace std
{

    template <typename TKey, typename TData,
              class Compare,
              class Alloc
             >
    void test_multimap<TKey, TData, Compare, Alloc>::clear()
    {
        multimap<TKey, TData>::clear();
    }

}
```

There are two additional problems with your code:

- As JBL says in his comment, it is not a good idea to inherit from STL containers because they have no virtual destructor. Your `test_multimap` will appear to work, but as soon as someone tries to use it polymorphically and delete a `test_multimap` through a base class pointer he will run into undefined behaviour.
- Adding classes to the `std` namespace is forbidden by the Standard (§17.6.4.2.1/1: *The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified.*). Just use a different namespace.

Comment: Gorpik, Now, it became clear for me. Thank you, I didn't guess itself to this decision. And thanks for other found errors, I will remake in a different way

p.s. Adding class to std namespace - is the homework